# The click event of selenium cannot be ended

Tags: python, selenium, click, block, suspend

Why do I open the file upload window after clicking the file upload button in the selenium click method, but the subsequent code has not been executed? Is there any reason for blocking? Who can help me?

The last line of code is not executed: print('After clicking the button')

Code Example:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from utils.config import app_name

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = R'G:\MapStudio\AUTEL Mapper\pkg-90897c37_b84bf016\win-unpacked\AUTEL Mapper.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
sleep(5)
print('Before')
ele = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div')
print('Click')
ele.click()
print('After')
```

[image]

```
I hope to execute the last code after clicking
```

Comment: And what would be the url of the page you're accessing and clicking on?

Comment: I see from your red dot there you've activated a breakpoint. Are you by any chance running in Debugging without knowing it?

Comment: it looks like breakpoint.

Comment: The code is still running and it is waiting for some actions from the user, check the IDE and your browser.

Comment: It is an electron application, not a web page.

Comment: I do not run in debug mode,I click run to run